# Which kinds of SPSS commands require EXECUTE and which do not?

Tags: transformation, spss, execution

SPSS [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/spss-statistics/27.0.0?topic=execute-overview-command) indicates that `EXECUTE` is "designed for use" with *transformation* commands and

> facilities such as `ADD FILES`, `MATCH FILES`, `UPDATE`, `PRINT`, and `WRITE`,
> which do not read data and are not executed unless followed by a
> data-reading procedure.

Is there a way of determining at a high level which commands are *not* "transformation" commands or* are commands that do not read data without investigating every single command before use to determine whether or not the command needs to be executed?

*I'm assuming it's "or" here and not "and"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, no command actually "needs" and `EXECUTE` command. If every transformation is executed immediately, and separately, it can cause longer processing time than when you run a list of transformations simultaneously.

You only need to `EXECUTE` when you want to see, or use, the results of the transformations. That's why if you run any analysis (eg. frequencies) on your data, transformations will run automatically.

In principle, you could run a long syntax without a single `EXECUTE` command - a `save` command at the end also runs pending transformations automatically (as does `sort cases`).

You should be aware though that there are (rare) situations where you need to run transformations before you move on to your next command. For example, if you use the `write` command to create a new syntax and then `insert` that syntax - you have to `EXECUTE` first or the new syntax will still be empty. Another example is if you use `add files` on a dataset that has pending transformations, you will be getting the pre-transformed data. So you should use `EXECUTE` before adding the files. There are also more complex scenarios e.g. transforming results of a `lag` function, but these are rare.

So to summarize: No command NEEDS to be executed. Use `EXECUTE` only when you need to see the results or use them in specific operations that require it (and then only if you didn't use other commands like save, sort or analyses that automatically execute anyway).